Why does Ubuntu app center open but then closes right away24.04
It is a lenovo G560 laptop
I installed it on 5/6/2024
The app center opens but then closes suddenly why?

It's bugged to the core. I also had similar issue and I updated it just a week ago. It was bugged to the core but lately I don't know what I installed but it's just opens. In the meantime just install through command line and use this website https://snapcraft.io/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does this answer your question? App Center opens as a blank screen in 23.10
